# Can I compose functions and types dynamically in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement a type of filter graph. This filter graphed is based on a math algorithm I've implemented that, simply, defines a set of functors that take some input and produce some type of output. I've implemented each of these functors as distinct classes in C++, with a common base type to allow the functors to be combined together.

Below is a very simple implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cctype>

// Simple filter that takes a string and returns some new type
template <typename A>
struct Filter {
    virtual A filter(const std::string& input) = 0;
};

// Takes a single char, returns that same char
struct SingleChar : public Filter<char> {
    char filter(const std::string& input) {
        assert(input.size() == 1);
        return input[0];
    }
};

// Takes a string, returns a pair of data types
template <typename A, typename B>
struct Sequence : public Filter<std::pair<A, B>> {
    Filter<A>* left;
    Filter<B>* right;

    std::pair<A, B> filter(const std::string& input) {
        assert(input.size() > 1);
        return std::make_pair(left->filter(input.substr(0, 1)), right->filter(input.substr(1)));
    }
};

template <typename B, typename A>
struct Transform : public Filter<A> {
    Filter<B>* innerFilter;
    std::function<A(B)> transform;

    A filter(const std::string& input) {
        return transform(innerFilter->filter(input));
    }
};

// Simple helper function to join two strings with a space
std::string joinStringPair(std::pair<std::string, std::string> pair) {
    return pair.first + ' ' + pair.second;
}

int main() {
    // Takes a single char, returns that same char (i.e. "A" -> "A")
    SingleChar singleLetter;

    // Takes a single char, returns that same char + it's lower-case version (i.e. "A" -> "Aa")
    Transform<char, std::string> letterAndLower;
    letterAndLower.innerFilter = &singleLetter;
    letterAndLower.transform = [](char c){ return std::string(1, c) + std::string(1, std::tolower(c)); };

    // Takes two chars, returns each one + its lower-case version (i.e. "AB" -> "Aa", "Bb")
    Sequence<std::string, std::string> twoLetterPair;
    twoLetterPair.left = &letterAndLower;
    twoLetterPair.right = &letterAndLower;

    // Takes two chars, returns them and their lower-case versions joined with a space (i.e. "AB" -> "Aa Bb")
    Transform<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string> twoLetterString;
    twoLetterString.innerFilter = &twoLetterPair;
    twoLetterString.transform = joinStringPair;

    // Takes three chars, returns each one + its lower-case version and space-joins the last two (i.e. "ABC" -> "Aa", "Bb Cc")
    Sequence<std::string, std::string> threeLetterPair;
    threeLetterPair.left = &letterAndLower;
    threeLetterPair.right = &twoLetterString;

    // Takes three chars, returns them and their lower-case versions joined with a space (i.e. "ABC" -> "Aa Bb Cc")
    Transform<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::string> threeLetterString;
    threeLetterString.innerFilter = &threeLetterPair;
    threeLetterString.transform = joinStringPair;

    // Outputs "Aa Bb Cc"
    std::cout << threeLetterString.filter("ABC") << std::endl;

    // Outputs "Xx Yy Zz"
    std::cout << threeLetterString.filter("XYZ") << std::endl;
}
```

The above simple example is all hard coded. The real implementation dynamically builds this filter graph. Consider the following simple example that builds the filter graph at run time based on a dynamically provided argument. Yes, it's trivial, but it illustrates the point that the polymorphism abstracts away the exact data types (for example, the returned `Transform`'s `innerFiler` could be a `SingleChar` or a `Sequence`). Hopefully this example makes it easier to imagine a more complex process that builds a graph with node types that would be different with different user-provided inputs (and involves many more types than just `char` and `string`).

```
Filter<std::string>* makeStringFilter(int stringLength) {
    // (ignore the memory leaks with not explicitly deleting allocated memory;
    // I'm ignoring memory leaks in this naive example for simplicity's sake)
    if (stringLength == 1) {
        // Take a single char, transform it to a string
        Transform<char, std::string>* transform = new Transform<char, std::string>;
        transform->innerFilter = new SingleChar;
        transform->transform = [](char c){ return std::string(1, c); };
        return transform;
    }

    // Take a char and string pair (like a car, cdr pair in Lisp)
    Sequence<char, std::string>* sequence = new Sequence<char, std::string>;
    sequence->left = new SingleChar;
    sequence->right = makeStringFilter(stringLength - 1);

    // Turn the pair into a proper string
    Transform<std::pair<char, std::string>, std::string>* transform = new Transform<std::pair<char, std::string>, std::string>;
    transform->innerFilter = sequence;
    transform->transform = [](std::pair<char, std::string> pair){ return pair.first + pair.second; };

    return transform;
}

// Using the above function; outputs "Hello world!" (fails on strings with length != 12)
Filter<std::string>* sixLetterString = makeStringFilter(12);
std::cout << sixLetterString->filter("Hello world!") << std::endl;
```

As part of my program, I build, traverse, and manipulate these graphs a lot. In practice, lots of nested `Transform` nodes build up in the process (especially when repeatedly manipulating a graph), so a graph ends up looking like:

```
... -> Transform -> Transform -> Transform -> ... -> Transform -> SingleChar
```

All these nested `Transform`s cause the graph to grow quite large, which increases traversal and manipulation times. Ideally, I'd like to compact all these nested `Transform`s together into one single transform node (so the graph is just `... -> Transform -> SingleChar`). This can be done by making a new `Transform` node that just composes all the `Transform`s' `Transform::transform` functions and points directly to the last `SingleChar`.

However, I'm running into issues with C++'s static typing and compacting these `Transform`s. In a dynamically typed language, compaction is easy because I can just compose the `Transform`s and the types all work out at runtime. But getting the typing to work in C++ is a headache.

The reason is because the `innerFilter` of a `Transform` is just a polymorphic pointer. If I have a `Transform<B, A>` with an `innerFilter` that points to a `Transform<C, B>`, that `innerFilter` just has has a polymorphic type `Filter<B>`. In order to compact these two `Transform`s, I need to create a new transform with type `Transform<C, A>`. The problem is, though, that the type `C` has been "erased" by the polymorphism; I only have types `A` and `B`.

Is it possible to compact these transforms? I've looked into type erasure, but it doesn't seem like a solution. Polymorphic template functions (understandably) aren't legal in C++. Static polymorphism (à la [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) isn't useful here, because I build, traverse, and manipulate these filter graphs at run time depending on user input.

I'm willing to revise the implementation completely to get this to work. The exact implementation isn't fixed; however, it needs to have the same overall functionality and type safety that this implementation has. I'm theorizing a new implementation is necessary (if this is possible at all) since you can't dynamically create new types at run time in C++, which is what it seems like this would require for compacting nested transforms in this implementation.

Comment: This isn't 100% clear.  What, in pseudo-C++, would you like to be able to write?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I was worried about that. I'll try and see if I can revise it to make it clearer....

Comment: A see a little contradiction here: you mention here, that transforms are built dynamically, based on user input. But for transforms you use templates that have static types A and B.

Comment: @MikhailMaltsev: The types `A` and `B` are static, yes, but I build a the tree at run time, based on user input, with node types that might be different for different inputs. I added a simple sample function that builds a graph at run time based on a dynamic parameter. Hopefully that helps a little.

Comment: This still isn't clear (to me, at least).  If you're building something at *runtime*, how do you want the *compile-time* type system to help you?

Answer (score 0):

I think this works. First, create a class that can combine any 2 Transform:

```
// First transform takes and A and returns a B, second takes a B and returns a C
template<A, B, C>
struct TwoTransform {
   std::function<B(A)> t1;
   std::function<C(B)> t2;
   TwoTransform(std::function<B(A)> t1, std::function<C(B)> t2) {
      this.t1 = t1;
      this.t2 = t2;
    }

    C filter(A input) {
        return t2(t1(input));
    }
}
```

Then, you can build a method to your TwoTransform that takes another Transform and returns yet another TwoTransform:

```
template<A, B, C>
struct TwoTransform {
  // Same code as above
  TwoTransform<A, C, D> addAnother(std::function<D(C)> nextOne) {
      return new TwoTransform(this, nextOne);
   }
}
```

So you can use this like:

```
Transform<A, B> t1;
Transofrm<B, C> t2;
Transform<C, D> t3;
Transform<D, E> t4;

Transform<A, E> final = new TwoTransform(t1, t2).addAnother(t3).addAnother(t4);
```

Please note: I've been writing Java lately and didn't try to above; I have a suspicious that I've used Java syntax instead of C++ in a few places, but hopefully you get the general idea.

Comment: The problem here is that you have the full types for `t1`, `t2`, `t3`, and `t4`. In my code, I do not have the full types. I have polymorphic pointers (`Filter<A>*`, for example), which means the `std::function` members are hidden (and I don't know how to access them, since I don't know the full type of the object so I can't do any casts).

Comment: @Cornstalks, I don't completely understand your comment. From your sample code it looked like you knew the types of the filters you were adding. If you don't, and you intentionally want to forgo type safety you can use (or create) something like create a [variant class](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant.html) and just have all your Transforms take and return Variant.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably to use expression templates, people like Todd Veldhuizen invented it to fold vector and matrix instructions.

Please read his paper http://ubietylab.net/ubigraph/content/Papers/pdf/CppTechniques.pdf, especially chapters 1.9 and 1.10

Comment: I'm not sure how expression templates could be used here. The runtime polymorphism hides the template types involved.

Comment: Sorry, I thought expression tree of transforms is known at compile time. In such case it would help, otherwise only runtime reshuffling is the way to go